# pyspark Transpose dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe as given below

```
ID, Code_Num, Code,              Code1,  Code2,  Code3

10, 1,       A1005*B1003,       A1005,  B1003,  null

12, 2,       A1007*D1008*C1004, A1007,  D1008,  C1004
```

I need help on transposing the above dataset, and output should be displayed as below.

```
ID, Code_Num, Code,              Code_T

10, 1,        A1005*B1003,       A1005

10, 1,        A1005*B1003,       B1003

12, 2,        A1007*D1008*C1004, A1007

12, 2,        A1007*D1008*C1004, D1008

12, 2,        A1007*D1008*C1004, C1004
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Creating the `DataFrame`.

```
values = [(10, 'A1005*B1003', 'A1005', 'B1003',  None),(12, 'A1007*D1008*C1004', 'A1007',  'D1008',  'C1004')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['ID','Code','Code1','Code2','Code3'])
df.show()
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| ID|             Code|Code1|Code2|Code3|
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 10|      A1005*B1003|A1005|B1003| null|
| 12|A1007*D1008*C1004|A1007|D1008|C1004|
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

**Step 2:** Explode the `DataFrame` -

```
def to_transpose(df, by):

    # Filter dtypes and split into column names and type description
    cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in by))
    # Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns
    assert len(set(dtypes)) == 1, "All columns have to be of the same type"

    # Create and explode an array of (column_name, column_value) structs
    kvs = explode(array([
      struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val")) for c in cols
    ])).alias("kvs")

    return df.select(by + [kvs]).select(by + ["kvs.key", "kvs.val"])

df = to_transpose(df, ["ID","Code"]).drop('key').withColumnRenamed("val","Code_T")
df.show()
+---+-----------------+------+
| ID|             Code|Code_T|
+---+-----------------+------+
| 10|      A1005*B1003| A1005|
| 10|      A1005*B1003| B1003|
| 10|      A1005*B1003|  null|
| 12|A1007*D1008*C1004| A1007|
| 12|A1007*D1008*C1004| D1008|
| 12|A1007*D1008*C1004| C1004|
+---+-----------------+------+
```

In case you only want `non-Null` values in column `Code_T`, just run the statement below -

```
df = df.where(col('Code_T').isNotNull())
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply.

I have another column " Code_Num" in the same dataframe which is integer. Could you please suggest how to add an extra column to the above code.

Comment: Hi Sudeep, which dataframe? the initial or the output? Can you kindly specify that, or better - just edit your question. That way it will be easy for me to understand. How does output dataframe look like?

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for the confusion.

I meant initial dataframe .

Comment: Sudeep, please change the dataframe in question and then it will be tad easier for me to compose an answer.

Comment: Hi,

I have updated the initial dataframe. And as you suggested Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns, do i need to convert all the columns data type to same.

Comment: Just add Code_Num between ID and Code inside to_transpose() function. ["ID","Code_Num","Code"] That’s all. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hi,

I get an error as "# Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns". Is it because of ID and Code_Num are integer data type in my dataframe?

Comment: Thank You.

After changing column data types in the input/initial dataframe it works fine.

Comment: Great then. If the answer has helped you, you can accept it if you wish.

Comment: Hi,

Definitely this has helped me and i am accepting it. 
However could you please tell me, how do i transpose the data back to the initial dataframe. I want to transpose Code_T to Code1, Code2, Code3.....

Comment: You are asking an 'untranspose' of this transpose. That has to do with `pivot()` and is a different question all together. Please post a new question with clearly defined dataframes and paste the link here for me to look at. Thanks

Comment: Mind it that, you can only do the transpose back if you have a `pivot` column, which we deleted `.drop('key')` which would have contained Code1,Code2,Code3. This column has to be restated. Else you can't do it.

Comment: Hi,

I have another query. Could you please look into this. I have added an image for a better view of the data frame.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288577/find-and-replace-specific-portion-of-a-string-taking-values-from-another-column